# Initial static React HTML rendering with Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-html-loader

Is there a way to pre-generate the HTML structure of a (single route) React application directly in the HTML entry point?

Then the page will be able to display HTML (based on React initial state) before any JS is loaded.

I'm actually using [webpack-html-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader) but any other loader or plugin is welcome ;)

PS: May [static-site-generator-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/markdalgleish/static-site-generator-webpack-plugin) be of any help?

PS: I'm not using React Router

Comment: Have you tried server-side rendering?

Comment: @Bezzi Can you be more explicit? Like sharing a webpack.config :D I need to generate static HTML at build time

Comment: You can only do this if your whole page is static. No communication with API?

Answer (score 10):

If you want to use [static-site-generator-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/markdalgleish/static-site-generator-webpack-plugin) you first need to build a bundle with webpack `bundle.js` that exports a render function that takes following arguments.

- `locals` an object with various page metadata e.g. `title` that go into component parameters (traditionally thought of as template variables).
- `callback` a nodejs style `(err, result)` callback that you will call with your rendered html as the value for `result`

e.g.

```
// entry.js, compiled to bundle.js by webpack

module.exports = function render(locals, callback) {
  callback(null, 
      '<html>' + locals.greet + ' from ' + locals.path + '</html>');
};
```

It is in this function that you will instantiate your components (possibly via React Router if you want) and render them with [`ReactDOMServer.renderToString()`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring).

You will then specify the compiled `bundle.js` as `bundle` in your instantiation of `StaticSiteGeneratorPlugin` as well as your concrete routes in `paths` and in `locals` an object containing the above mentioned metadata values.

```
var paths, locals; // compute paths from metadata files or frontmatter

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    bundle: './entry.js' // build bundle.js from entry.js source
  },
  ...,
  plugins: [
    new StaticSiteGeneratorPlugin('bundle', paths, locals)
  ]
}
```

The keys you specify for `locals` in `webpack.config.js` in will be present in the `locals` parameter of every call to `render(locals, callback)`. They will be merged with `path`, `assets` and `webpackStats` keys provided by the plugin.

If you want to load javascript code into your pages after rendering you could compile an additional `page.js` entry to your webpack config that calls `ReactDOM.render()` in the typical manner and then load that bundle in a `script` tag emitted by in your `render(locals, callback)` function in your `bundle.js` (above). Ensure that `page.js` mounts components to the same location in the DOM as they are when rendered by `entry.js` (you will probably set an `id` attribute on the parent element). You will also need to ensure that any location (i.e. route path) dependent variables align in both environments.

Check out the source code of [Gatsby](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby) which also uses this plugin. You can also have a look at the source code for [Phenomic](https://phenomic.io/) for an alternative approach.

Answer (score 2):

You should try server side rendering, it will let react render the first view of your app in a backend and deliver a static HTML. [This boilerplate](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example) already comes with server rendering set up and you can learn more about it [here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/03/server-side-rendering-react-node-express/)

Comment: Sure, but I need it in a full static way (without express).. initial HTML rendering should happen one, at build time (when running webpack).. Any example to share?

Answer (score 0):

[Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) is great **static site generator** which can be extended with *custom ruby plugins*. You need to enable *WebPack* to make *Jekyll* calls. See [Plugging Webpack to Jekyll Powered Pages](https://www.jonathan-petitcolas.com/2016/08/12/plugging-webpack-to-jekyll-powered-pages.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a working example https://github.com/aganglada/preact-minimal/blob/master/config/webpack.config.js, if you like you can fork it and take a look at how this work all together.

Hope it helps :)